# Need Formula to calculate number of months into 2023 given duration and start date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

In an excel file I have been given the start date of a contract and it's duration. I need to get the number of months this contract will be active in 2023.

So for example if the start data is 10/1/2023 and duration is 12 the output I would need is 9 (subtracted 12-9 since the contract will be active 3 months into 2022 and 9 months into 2023). I have more examples below, is there a formula or a way to automate this in excel?

[image]

Comment: why would `1/1/2022` and `12` be `1` where `10/1/2022` and `12` be `9`?

Comment: In terms of a formula it was meant to be 0 and not 1

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your rounding rules.  Last line, the 12/31/22 ends 8/30/23, you rounded down to 7 even thought the project ran almost all of August.  The 9/6/22 project ends 5/5/23 and you still included all 5 months in 2023.  These contradict each other.  If a contract extends 1 day into June, 2023, do you want June counted?  If a project ends on June 29, leaving one day out-of-contract, do you want June counted?  Articulating *every* condition in plain language rules is the the necessary start to solving anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=IFERROR(MONTH(MIN(EDATE(A2-1,B2),DATE(2023,12,31))-MAX(A2,DATE(2023,1,1))),0)
```

We basically just subtract the max between column A and the first of Jan from the min between the date plus the number of months and the last day of 2023.

This gives us the number of days in 2023.  Then we simply take the MONTH of that number.

If it is <=0 then we will get an error and we assume 0.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `DATE(2023,12,31)`?  Also worth noting that, per my earlier comment, your mid-month project start/ends do not follow their rounding rules.  That's where I was having trouble, was trying to encode their rounding approach.

Comment: @Max yes I did mean 2023-12-31.  Thanks for the catch.  And yes I was assuming a lot with this formula.  I was hoping it would encourage questions and answers from the OP.  I fully expected to do some edits to fine tune what they mean by a "Month".